# How to change default mail sender (alias/via) when using Zend_Mail? i.e. remove "via" in gmail

Tags: sendmail, php, zend-mail

When I send email using Zend Mail using the following code:

```
    $to = array("email1@gmail.com","email2@hotmail.com","email3@yahoo.com");        
    $msg = file_get_contents("email.html");             
    $mail = new Zend_Mail ( "UTF-8" );
    $mail->setMessageId ( "MyMsg__" . md5 ( microtime () ) );
    $mail->addHeader ( "Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8" );
    $mail->setBodyHtml ( $msg  );
    $mail->setSubject ( "News Letter Test" );       
    $mail->setReplyTo('newsletter@mydomain.com', 'Some Name');
    $mail->addHeader('MIME-Version', '1.0');
    $mail->addHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', '8bit');
    $mail->addHeader('X-Mailer:', 'PHP/'.phpversion());
    $mail->setFrom ('newsletter@mydomain.com', 'Some Name');
    foreach($to as $ml){
        $mail->addTo ( $ml );       
    }
    $mail->send ( $transport );
```

I get this in gmail:

**newsletter@mydomain.com via u4552323.onlinehome-server.com**

How do I remove this part: **via u4552323.onlinehome-server.com**

Notice I have full root access and this is a dedicated server, if the problem is in send_mail config, or hosts, how do I change this part **u4552323.onlinehome-server.com** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google displays the 'via' information in Gmail in [when messages are sent through another domain](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1311182).  In your case, the message is coming from an address in the `mydomain.com` domain, but the mail server is in the `onlinehome-server.com` domain.

You can avoid this by sending mail through the SMTP server for the `mydomain.com` domain (assuming your hosting provider doesn't block such traffic).  If can control the DNS and mail server configuration for the `onlinehome-server.com` server, you can also configure SPF and DKIM, as explained in Google's documentation (but this may not be an option depending on your hosting environment).

Comment: I noticed that when I nslookup myIp it gives the server name in the via, how do I change that ?

Comment: You may want to check with your hosting provider to see if you can change the reverse DNS for your server.

Comment: I have full root access do I still need to check with them?

Comment: I'm not using their name servers, I'm using DNS manager for my domain in Godaddy, or the reverse dns is still @ the host?

Comment: Yes, your host will still control reverse DNS.